# System is running in low graphics mode

Tags: graphics

When I started Ubuntu 16.04, I got this on my screen:

[image]

I have Linux kernel 4.15. I upgraded it first from 4.10 to 4.13 and then to 4.15. I have tried upgrading the grub menu by doing `sudo upgrade-grub` and also by booting in the failsafeX mode. When I tried failsafeX mode, nothing happened, but I was just redirected to the same window that I was getting before.
It has happened for the second time and I noticed that before shutting down the last time when it was working fine, a red dot appeared in the horizontal menu bar above by left of the wifi icon with a black dash in it. when I clicked on that, some error message was shown but I don't remember it now. In short Ubuntu is not starting and I want to start it as usual. Pls help

Comment: I want to solve this problen. Ubuntu is not starting. Whenever I start it just displays the window that I have given as link. I want to solve this problem

Comment: @David Foerster I have edited the question. Now pls guide me upon how to tackle this

Comment: "some error message was shown but I don't remember it now"  Don't you think the error message might have been useful?  Does it happen every time? If so and if this were my question i'd probably reboot again and take the trouble to write it down so that you help us to help you.

Comment: Well now as I try to reboot and open Ubuntu nothing appears except than the above window. Probably I have to reinstall Ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](/q/141606/175814)

Comment: Yes but I have already followed those steps and couldn't find a fix